# Game gets slow if after playing 5-6 times in Cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is a new type of problem i am facing in my game . I can say that i have implemented all the code for the Game . But i am facing problem with it. Actually what happen is when i play it for more than **5-6 times** then game gets slower , means we can feel that it's going on slow. But it's FPS is 60 but the fluctuation in FPS  takes place between 60 to 30.

In my game I've implemented **ARC**. I also can see that every time **number of object that are present in the scene are same**.

I have also used instruments to check memory leak in the game but there is **no memory leak** in game. I can't show the code because its confidential.

But I couldn't be able to solve this problem. I would like to know what can be the reason behind this and How can i solve this issue.

Any kind of help can be helpful

Comment: I guess it's because of complex code and computation. How one should remove the complexity???

Comment: I accept down vote but at least leave reason in comment.. so that i can learn things from this.

Comment: I guess you're out of luck, since you can't somehow describe to us what you're doing.

Comment: As i clearly mentioned that, i can't show code here because its confidential. so if any one can't describe properly, without asking for more explanation you give down vote. Good good, I came to know new thing about stack overflows user.

Comment: ARC or no ARC, you could be retaining objects as you cycle your game, eg these objects which you consider (from a functional viewpoint) disposed, are still held i.e. they are not leaked. Confirm this by running a memory allocation profile and play your game in the simulator (to see memory allocated by textures). If MA is a flatliner, your problem is not about memory.

Comment: I run memory allocation profile and played my game, what i got is it occupies 85-95% of CPU, 4 threads , 130-140 MB real memory and 416 MB virtual memory. Can you please tell me any thing wrong in this?

Comment: This values stays constant , every time i play game.

Comment: hmmm ... 130-140 seems high. You might be fighting with other processes in the device for memory. Good news that it is constant. You may want to look for opportunities to 'unload' part of the textures at appropriate times, for example during transitions between scenes, to try to bring back the total allocations to a more reasonable number.

Comment: Total allocation is the same as the number which appears at first place in bottom left corner right? If it is then it is always same when i restart the game

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: I performed heapshots in allocation profile, every time i am getting non-object of around 500 KB? Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I dont use the Apple toys to do this, i perform a heapshot-like analysis every time i run my apps : the facility to do that are built-in to every one of my classes, to enable me to determine exactly the number of instances currently allocated (not deallocated) at any point during program execution. It is a bit of work (say approximately 1 minute) per class when I add one to a project, but a life saver over the life of the project.

Coming back to your question above in the comments, no i have no clue about your 500K. The only person that can figure that out at this moment is you. If your game has a logical point (like a game main menu) where you can come back before quitting the app (i mean hard kill), at that place I would start by doing this, just after the menu is drawn :

```
// below code with cocos2d 2.x

NSLog(@"*** before purge ***");
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];

[CCAnimationCache purgeSharedAnimationCache];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(dumpTextures) delay:0.5f]; 

// let the run loop cycle a bit
// to give a chance for auto-release objects to be
// disposed from the pool ... 

-(void) dumpTextures {

    NSLog(@"*** after purge ***");
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];

}
```

and examine the result. Look for any texture that is cocos2d is still holding for you ... the most likely memory hog by far. I dont think that 5-6 times 500K would make much of a difference in a game that peaks around 140Mb.

Comment: hey, i tried what you say. And i got below information when i restart my game: ***before purge***  cocos2d: CCTextureCache dumpDebugInfo: 58 textures, for 56535 KB (55.21 MB) and ***After purge*** CCTextureCache dumpDebugInfo: 55 textures, for 53181 KB (51.94 MB)

Comment: So what should i do??? Should i have to remove other manually? By removing purge data, there is still 55 textures left before going to new game.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between leaking memory and abandoning memory. ARC helps with the leaks but it still allows you to retain strong references to your objects when they are no longer needed. An example of this is retain cycles.

You can perform a technique known as Heapshot Analysis. Using instruments it will show you what memory is being retained when it doesn't need to be anymore after a game has finished.

There is a tutorial on Heapshot here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: hey i performed Heapshot analysis for 4-5 times when i restart the game, and I am getting non-object of around 500 KB every time , do you know any thing about that, how to solve that...

Comment: yes Ben, i forgot to tell you thanx, any ways, Thanx for this tutorial...it helps me alot.